# Using FindAll in a List with instances from two derived classes

Tags: linq, list

**I wonder if the following is possible to accomplish with the FindAll-method:**

I have a base class called Animal. I have two derived classes called Fish and Dog.

Animal have:

```
public string Type { get; set; }
public int Height { get; set; }
public int Length { get; set; }
```

Dog have:

```
public string Color { get; set; }
```

Fish have: nothing extra.

I want to do something like this:

```
Console.Write("\nEnter keyword to search the farm: ");
string keyword = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

var mySearch = myAnimals.FindAll(p => p.Type.Contains(keyword) || p.Color.Contains(keyword));
```

myAnimals is a List of type Animal, containing instances of Fish and Dog.

```
List<Animal> myAnimals = new List<Animal>();
```

The problem is that Color cant be accessed from there. Only what's in the base class Animal, i.e. Type, Height and Length, are possible targets.

Comment: You would have to cast your "p" Object to Dog to access the property.
Or you use OfType<TResult> to pre-filter for Dogs: myAnimals.OfType<Dog>().FindAll(dog => dog.Color // now accessible

Comment: I actually was thinking in this direction and even used this code before. I got this error-message:

IEnumerable<Dog>' does not contain a definition for 'FindAll' and no extension method 'FindAll' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Dog>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @solojuve1897 Do the `.OfType<Dog>().ToList().FindAll(..` and now you should have FindAll extension method available.

Comment: Or simply use `.Where()` instead. But when you use `OfType()` you won't find all other animals. So maybe something like: `animals.FindAll(animal => animal.Type.Contains(keyword) || (((animal as Dog)?.Color.Contains(keyword)) ?? false));`

Comment: @The-First-Tiger that was exactly what I was looking for. Brilliant. Could you please explain this line in detail:

(((animal as Dog)?.Color.Contains(keyword)) ?? false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code:

```
animals.FindAll(animal => animal.Type.Contains(keyword) || (((animal as Dog)?.Color.Contains(keyword)) ?? false));
```

So what does the part `(((animal as Dog)?.Color?.Contains(keyword)) ?? false)` actually do?

Let's take it into parts:

`(animal as Dog)` tries to cast animal to the Type `Dog`. If this fails there is no exception thrown, instead it returns `null`

As we cannot access the property `Color` of `null` (this would lead to a `NullReferenceException`) we need to use the `?.` Operator aka [Null-conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx). It will only try to access `Color` if `(animal as Dog)` is not `null`.
If `(animal as Dog)` is null the whole expression becomes `null`.
The same with `Color?.Contains()` as Color itself could be `null`.

As we need a boolean expression after `||` and `null` would not be boolean we also use the `??` Operator aka [Null-coalescing Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). If the expression on the left is `null` use the value on the right. Otherwise use the value on the left.

This means if `animal` is a Dog which has a Color property and this property is not null use the return value of `Contains(keyword)` which is true or false.
Otherwise if `animal` is not a Dog or Color is null default to `false`.
`Type.Contains(keyword)|| false` means whatever `Type.Contains(keyword)` returns.

But this becomes unflexible if you add more types. What could be another approach?

E.g. using a [custom Attibute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
class Animal
{
    [SearchableProperty]
    public string Type { get; set;}

    public string ImNotSearchable { get; set;}
}

class Fish : Animal { }

class Dog : Animal
{
    [SearchableProperty]
    public string Color { get; set;}
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false)]
class SearchablePropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
}

animals.FindAll(animal => animal.GetType().GetProperties().Where(
                prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(SearchablePropertyAttribute))).Any(p => p.GetValue(animal)?.ToString()?.Contains(keyword) ?? false))
```

But be aware that these kind of things can be inefficient for larger datasets.